# What is the purpose of "setApplicationName" in the Google APIs Java client library?

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I can't seem to find any information on the Application Name used by various Google API services.  The best I can figure is that it might simply be a name that will display on the consent screen?  Below is an example of the application name I'm talking about.

```
calendarService = new Calendar.Builder( HTTP_TRANSPORT , JSON_FACTORY , credential )
        .setApplicationName( applicationName )
        .build();
```

Also, if I create multiple calendarServices, would/should I give each a unique application name?

Answer (score 0):

```
setApplicationName( applicationName )
```

I beleave that the name displayed to the user on the consent screen is configured in Google developer console when you set up the Client screen.

As far as I know the Application name is sent as part of the user agent Header on all HTTP requests to google but you will need to check the Google api java client.

Update:

Its definatly used for the UserAgent header : [AbstractGoogleClient.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/91401e905ba72e513918844e41dd8a3159d33b2c/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient.java#L446)

Comment: I'm not sure what the significance of it being used in the UserAgent is.  Can I just stick any random name in that field for each service?  Can I repeat the same name for each service?

Comment: IMO You can just stick any random string in there you like as far as i can tell thats all its used for.

Comment: If I create multiple calendar services would using the same application name for each cause any problem?